# insert a domain name into servlet authentication token

Tags: java, servlets, arrays, jna, waffle

I am using [Waffle](http://dblock.github.com/waffle/) for an SSO solution in my web-app.

Everything works fine but I would like to modify some functionality slightly:

Currently, if a user is not connected to the domain the SSO fails and opens a little authorization dialog:

[image]

The windows authorization requires the user name formatted like `Domain\Username` but most of my users will not know to add the domain in front of their username. So I would like to provide a default domain name if one is not specified.

I found a waffle function that I can override which will give me access to the decoded authentication token, I added a `println` to the waffle function and it shows the username in plain text (either with or without the domain depending on what is typed in the dialog):

```
public IWindowsSecurityContext acceptSecurityToken(String connectionId, byte[] token, String securityPackage) {

    // I can see the passed username in the logs with this
    System.out.println(new String(token));

    // I don't understand any of the JNA stuff below this comment:
    IWindowsCredentialsHandle serverCredential = new WindowsCredentialsHandleImpl(
            null, Sspi.SECPKG_CRED_INBOUND, securityPackage);
    serverCredential.initialize();

    SecBufferDesc pbServerToken = new SecBufferDesc(Sspi.SECBUFFER_TOKEN, Sspi.MAX_TOKEN_SIZE);
    SecBufferDesc pbClientToken = new SecBufferDesc(Sspi.SECBUFFER_TOKEN, token);

    NativeLongByReference pfClientContextAttr = new NativeLongByReference();

    CtxtHandle continueContext = _continueContexts.get(connectionId);

    CtxtHandle phNewServerContext = new CtxtHandle();
    int rc = Secur32.INSTANCE.AcceptSecurityContext(serverCredential.getHandle(), 
            continueContext, pbClientToken, new NativeLong(Sspi.ISC_REQ_CONNECTION), 
            new NativeLong(Sspi.SECURITY_NATIVE_DREP), phNewServerContext, 
            pbServerToken, pfClientContextAttr, null);

    WindowsSecurityContextImpl sc = new WindowsSecurityContextImpl();
    sc.setCredentialsHandle(serverCredential.getHandle());
    sc.setSecurityPackage(securityPackage);
    sc.setSecurityContext(phNewServerContext);

    switch (rc)
    {
        case W32Errors.SEC_E_OK:
            // the security context received from the client was accepted
            _continueContexts.remove(connectionId);
            //  if an output token was generated by the function, it must be sent to the client process
            if (pbServerToken != null 
                    && pbServerToken.pBuffers != null
                    && pbServerToken.cBuffers.intValue() == 1 
                    && pbServerToken.pBuffers[0].cbBuffer.intValue() > 0) {
                sc.setToken(pbServerToken.getBytes());
            }
            sc.setContinue(false);
            break;
        case W32Errors.SEC_I_CONTINUE_NEEDED:
            // the server must send the output token to the client and wait for a returned token
            _continueContexts.put(connectionId, phNewServerContext);
            sc.setToken(pbServerToken.getBytes());
            sc.setContinue(true);
            break;
        default:
            sc.dispose();
            WindowsSecurityContextImpl.dispose(continueContext);
            _continueContexts.remove(connectionId);
            throw new Win32Exception(rc);
    }

    return sc;
}
```

That whole function is from the Waffle API I only added the println at the beginning.

The passed username prints in plain text inside this token between a bunch of random byte chars (ÉsR=ÍtÍö?æ¸+Û-).

I am admittedly in very far over my head with JNA and java in general but I thought that because I can see the username here there must be a way to prepend the domain name to the username part of this token? I could be wrong.

My other idea was to add the domain to the `pbClientToken` that is created from the raw byte[] token this method is passed.

The `pbClientToken` is a [JNA `Structure` object](http://jna.java.net/javadoc/platform/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Sspi.SecBufferDesc.html) derivative. It has the `Stucture` method `writeField` which looked promising but I can't seem to figure out what field I should write. The `Structure.getFields` method doesn't seem to be available from `pbClientToken`.

I was hoping that this was a simple problem for someone more familiar with byte[] processing or JNA.

Comment: @dblock you may know something about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this. What happens behind this dialog is a call to LogonUser on the user's machine, which gives you a ticket, which is then sent to the server. Unfortunately the server is not in the same domain, so even if you manage to extract the username it's completely useless.